# Count numbers of nested divs with certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get number of all divs with class `col-md-6 col-xs-12` inside the following structure:

```
<div class="Numbers_List_Main col-xs-12">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12"></div>
</div>
```

i tried JQuery find as following:

```
$(".Numbers_List_Main col-xs-12").find(".row").find(".col-md-6 col-xs-12").length
```

but it doesn't work, any idea about how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the `class selector` properly,

```
$(".Numbers_List_Main.col-xs-12 .row .col-md-6.col-xs-12").length
```

This situation is like, we have to select an element with two classes. So the class selector has to be combined by `.class1.class2`.

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/by6ays9d/)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$('.col-md-6.col-xs-12').length;
```

Answer (score 0):

If i quite right your point, i believe, it should count number of div elements with strictly named class attribute (for example, class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-lg-6" is not suitable). Therefore I suggest you following solution:
Using jQuery approach:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log($("div[class='col-md-6 col-xs-12']").length);
});
```